# CSS3 transormation doesn't work on DIV elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to perform "Flip card" effect on div elemenets (card). To to that I am using code below (i applied onclick event but I didn't iclude it here). Does someone knows where is the problem ? I want to flip "Card" Div element. To to that I am using "OpenCard()" JavaScript function that I included below.

EDIT 1: Added jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9CvYd/1/

JavaScript:

```
    function OpenCard() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    if ($("#" + id + " img").is(":hidden")) {
        var img = document.querySelector("#" + id + " img");
        img.classList.toggle("flip");

        if (ImgOpened == "") {
            BoxOpened = id;
            ImgOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
            }, 300);
        } else {
            CurrentOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            if (ImgOpened != CurrentOpened) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.querySelector("#" + id + " img").classList.toggle("flip");
                    document.querySelector("#" + BoxOpened + " img").classList.toggle("flip");
                    BoxOpened = "";
                    ImgOpened = "";
                }, 400);
                Counter-=10;
                wrong.play();
            } else {
                $("#" + id + " img").parent().css("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").parent().css("disabled", "disabled");
                ImgFound++;
                BoxOpened = "";
                ImgOpened = "";
                Counter+=100;
                correct.play();
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
            }, 400);
        }
        $("#counter").html("" + Counter);

        if (ImgFound == ImgSource.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert ("Game over! You result is: "+Counter);
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
 #picbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard {
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}

#boxcard div{
    float: left;
    width: 100;
    height: 120;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: #B1B1B1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#boxcard > div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
#boxcard div img {
    /*display: none;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#boxcard div img.flip{

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
   display:inline-block;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="boxcard" align="center">
            <div id="card10" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699263b01721074bf094aa3bc695aa19c8d573.png" class=""></div>
            <div id="card11" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png" class=""></div>
            <div id="card12" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png"></div>
```

Comment: You should really create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) reproducing your specific issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YffE5/

Comment: Thanks for help @sharshi . You forgot to add onclick event to divs. I edited post and added jsfiddle

Comment: @ZachSaucier how can I do that without JS ?

Comment: I retract my statement. It's just messy

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if` statement condition is not matching.

Click a card here:  http://jsfiddle.net/YffE5/1/

```
if ($("#" + id + " img").is(":hidden")) // Image is visible, thus code inside this will not execute.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Coby. I removed that if statement but div (or card) are not flipping...

Comment: I cannot possibly help in debugging that code as majority of the variables are undefined with the partial code you've provided. I suspect you didn't write this code, as you don't understand it.